# Why is there such a difference between the study material for the FAA and EASA ATP knowledge tests?

Tags: faa, jet, icao, airline-pilot, easa

What's the difference between the FAA & EASA ATPL written/knowledge test?

The FAA test seems way easier; you just study the Gleim which has 1650+ multiple choice questions and composed of 1,048 pages.

The EASA test which seems very difficult; you have to study the complete set of Jeppesen EASA ATPL training which is 15 manuals/books and composed of almost 3,900 pages!!

So why is there a huge difference between the study materials for the various tests?

Comment: Hello Karim. Is there some reason you have for reverting edits to the title of this question?

Comment: Just correcting spelling mistakes and making title clearer